# Stop another method from running because of another's return?

Tags: objective-c, methods, return

Very basic Objective C question that I can't believe I haven't run into before. If I have a method with a return; in a conditional, the rest of the method will not run. But say if I have a method with another method call with returns.. how do I make the parent method stop running because the child has a return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluate the return value of the child method and decide on it if you should return or not in the callee methoed.

Comment: I'm actually really struggling. Can you edit your answer and give me an example? Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out... the child could be - (int) child method { and could return 1 or 0 and then in the parent call and test with if([self heroCheckTileCollision]==1){ return}

Comment: Very good, you could increase the readability of your if you turn int return type to BOOL as you may only evaluate on two states.

Answer (score 1):

You should test for the return value in the calling method, and return from that calling method if appropriate.

```
if (![self subMethodOK]) {
    return NO;
}
```